# How to easily merge/blend multiple images together in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, blending

For a project I have to merge and blend multiple images of ruined cities, ive been trying to use photoshop to merge and blend but I cant seem to make it look 'clean', anyone know any ways that I could do this. 
**SPECIFICATION:**

- I want merge multiple city scapes together
- I want to keep the depth and main part of the city scapes but remove the background and blend

I dont know whats the best way of doing this?
Some images I would like to work with are included below:
[image: damaged building[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKMOn.jpg)[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyg3d.jpg)
[[image: damaged[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Xka.jpg)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScslH.jpg)

Comment: more information about how you want to "blend" them might be helpful, also if you could give us some example of the images you are working with, as well as the finished product you are looking to achieve.

Comment: I'd recommend using google and going through some tutorials. The first result: 
https://www.photoshoptutorials.ws/photoshop-tutorials/photo-manipulation/a-photo-manipulators-guide-to-blending/

Will take you through a lot of the techniques used in photomanipulation.

Comment: I have added images if that helps @Ovaryraptor

Comment: I still dont understand what you are looking for as your final result. these images are going to very hard to combine. as the perspectives are different, and they are not photos, but illustrations.

Comment: @RaGeMaGiXZ Again see my previous comment. 1- Pick good COHESIVE images. 2-Learn how to mesh images.

Flagging as unclear if or until you edit it with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

The reality is these are done by those *very proficient* in digital painting.

There's no "easy" technique here.

You use the photos as a **basis** for actually painting.Then you spend a great deal of time painting and blending much like one would do in traditional painting.

If you are interested in this type of art, you need to study digital painting. There are several books and tutorials out there.

- https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/how-to/create-digital-painting.html
- http://www.creativebloq.com/features/digital-painting-with-photoshop-cc-for-beginners
- https://www.pluralsight.com/paths/photoshop